# Access-Control-Allow-Origin header contains multiple values *, *

Tags: c#, rest, web-services, cors

I'm building REST Web Service using c#.

The I have a web application that is installed in another server. If I try to call any of these web services, I get this error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://test.domain.com/WS/Hab-Dem/Tar/api/Login' from origin 'https://std.apps.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed.

I have created this file:

```
public class PreflightRequestsHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request.Headers.Contains("Origin") && request.Method.Method.Equals("OPTIONS"))
        {
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK };

            // Define and add values to variables: origins, headers, methods (can be global) 
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Request-Headers", "*");

            var tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
            tsc.SetResult(response);

            return tsc.Task;
        }

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

In `WebApiConfig.cs` I have inserted this code:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services
    config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*", "X-Custom-Header"));
    config.MessageHandlers.Add(new PreflightRequestsHandler()); // Defined above
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } );

    var jsonConfig = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
    jsonConfig.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
}
```

And in `web.config` file I have added this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
        <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" 
             type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
             preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    // Website you wish to allow to connect
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

  // Request methods you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

  // Request headers you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers,X-Access-Token,XKey,Authorization');

//  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/blocked-by-cors-policy-the-access-control-allow-origin-mean-stack

Comment: In PreflightRequestsHandler class.

Comment: set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://test.domain.com/WS/Hab-Dem/Tar/api/Login

Comment: I don't have res.setHeader method.

Comment: I'm try to set your code in my PreflightRequestesHandler class but the error is the same

Comment: response.Headers.Add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers,X-Access-Token,XKey,Authorization');
response.Headers.Add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','https://std.apps.com');

Can you please try with above 2 lines?